# Fedora LAMP: Problem include configuration file

Tags: apache2, fedora, apache, fedora-core

I've been configuring LAMP server on Fedora core 13 and when I tr to include my configuration files from within

/etc/http/conf/httpd.conf

using apache's Include directive, apache just fails on restart action.

What is the problem, is there any problems on Selinux stack?

Sultan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**you need never edit this file:** */etc/http/conf/httpd.conf*

**You need put your own configuration file in:** */etc/httpd/conf.d*

After you can restart http.d service

```
$ su -lc 'service httpd start'
```

You can check your configuration

```
$ su -lc 'service httpd configtest'
  Syntax OK
```

If all is good:

```
$ su -lc 'service httpd reload'
```